# Locating Rogue Perl Script

Tags: ubuntu, web-hosting, perl, security

I've been trying to source the location of a perl script which is causing havoc on a server which I control. I'm also trying to find out exactly how this script was installed on the server - my best guess is through a WordPress exploit.

The server is a basic web setup running Ubuntu 9.04, Apache and MySQL. I use IPTables as the firewall. the site runs around 20 sites and the load never really creeps above 0.7.

From what I can see the script is making outbound connection to other servers (most likely trying to brute force entry).

Here is a top dump of one of the processes:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND  
  22569 www-data  20   0 22784 3216  780 R  100  0.2  47:00.60 perl
```

The command the process is running is `/usr/sbin/sshd`. I've tried to find an exact file name but I'm having no luck... I've run an `lsof -p PID` and here is the output:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE    SIZE   NODE NAME
perl    22569 www-data  cwd    DIR    8,6    4096      2 /
perl    22569 www-data  rtd    DIR    8,6    4096      2 /
perl    22569 www-data  txt    REG    8,6   10336 162220 /usr/bin/perl
perl    22569 www-data  mem    REG    8,6   26936 170219 /usr/lib/perl/5.10.0/auto/Socket/Socket.so
perl    22569 www-data  mem    REG    8,6   22808 170214     /usr/lib/perl/5.10.0/auto/IO/IO.so
perl    22569 www-data  mem    REG    8,6   39112 145112 /lib/libcrypt-2.9.so
perl    22569 www-data  mem    REG    8,6 1502512 145124 /lib/libc-2.9.so
perl    22569 www-data  mem    REG    8,6  130151 145113 /lib/libpthread-2.9.so
perl    22569 www-data  mem    REG    8,6  542928 145122 /lib/libm-2.9.so
perl    22569 www-data  mem    REG    8,6   14608 145125 /lib/libdl-2.9.so
perl    22569 www-data  mem    REG    8,6 1503704 162222 /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.10.0
perl    22569 www-data  mem    REG    8,6  135680 145116 /lib/ld-2.9.so
perl    22569 www-data    0r  FIFO    0,6         157216 pipe
perl    22569 www-data    1w  FIFO    0,6         197642 pipe
perl    22569 www-data    2w  FIFO    0,6         197642 pipe
perl    22569 www-data    3w  FIFO    0,6         197642 pipe
perl    22569 www-data    4u  IPv4 383991            TCP outsidesoftware.com:56869->server12.34.56.78.live-servers.net:www (ESTABLISHED)
```

My gut feeling is outsidesoftware.com is also under attack? Or possibly being used as a tunnel.

I've managed to find a number of rogue files in `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`, here is a brief output of one of these files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# this spreader is coded by xdh
# xdh@xxxxxxxxxxx
# only for testing...

my @nickname = ("vn");
my $nick = $nickname[rand scalar @nickname];
my $ircname = $nickname[rand scalar @nickname];

#system("kill -9 `ps ax |grep httpdse |grep -v grep|awk '{print $1;}'`");
my $processo = '/usr/sbin/sshd';
```

The full file contents can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/yenFRrGP

I'm trying to achieve a couple of things here...

1. Firstly I need to stop these processes from running. Either by disabling outbound SSH or any IP Tables rules etc... these scripts have been running for around 36 hours now and my main concern is to stop these things running and respawning by themselves.
2. Secondly I need to try and source where and how these scripts have been installed. If anybody has any advice on what to look for in access logs or anything else I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Never ever allow 'exec' bit on filesystems where untrusted users can write files! Update your /etc/fstab and remount, or better reboot the server.

Here you (finally) realized that firewall is not fancy thing to just "protect" you against some idiotic attacks from outside. You must have firewall rules for outgoing traffic as well! Or at least you should have some monitoring of outgoing traffic. OK, wordpress would like to update itself via http (?) but why should some web app connect to ssh, irc etc...?

Next thing... Ah, it is runs all your sites under 'www-data'. That's very great. You should design it in better way. Run each user-client under its own separated uid. You could use php-fpm or something similar. This way you would have better view on your users' activity and you could even filter via iptables traffic based on userid... Does a user 'foobar' need his web app connect to an irc server? Then nothing more simple than adding a rule just for this specific user.

Another point... Ports < 1024 can be bind only by root user. Then you should have some kind of monitoring of listening ports > 1024, so a user would not have its own daemon listening on your server.

You could also think about chrooting web apps...

If any untrusted user can run its own binaries, scripts on the server, then there's access to user server or they can user your resources for something else.

Some interesting info about securing PHP hosting: [Linux: 25 PHP Security Best Practices For Sys Admins](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-security-best-practices-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will look at the suggestions you make and improve going forward. We have looked into chrooting on web apps and this is something we will look at going forward.  At this stage im looking on how to stop the on-going issues. Can you suggest any IP tables rules that will help?

Comment: I have no easy answer. How would you distinguish between valid outgoing traffic and bad one? All web apps run under same user and they can do "good" things while connecting to internet (update of web app itself, imap access...). Maybe some layer 7 inspection? If you have separate filesystem for /var/tmp and /tmp remount them with 'noexec'. Do you host perl web apps? If not, try to exclude 'www-data' from being able to execute perl binary (see ACL, setfacl). Sorry, no real answer...

Comment: Thanks for your help, good idea excluding www-data from executing perl. Thanks

Comment: I made to run sshd under normal user like this: /usr/sbin/sshd -f /tmp/sshd_config -h /tmp/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -h /tmp/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -h /tmp/ssh/ssh_host_key -D -d
So your bad user got ssh access to user server :)

Comment: If you would have selinux enabled/configured, you would be better protected from your bad web security design...

Comment: Hm... setfacl -m u:www-data:--- /usr/sbin/sshd /usr/bin/perl ???

Answer (score 0):

You said "I'm also trying to find out exactly how this script was installed on the server - my best guess is through a WordPress exploit. The server is a basic web setup running Ubuntu 9.04"

Ubuntu 9.04 was a non-long-term-support release and stopped receiving updates end of 2010:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2010-September/001166.html

so basically your SSH, Apache and all services have not received security updates in ages! Your best bet is to consider this server as 'lost' and not spent any time chasing the script. You can have rootkits and all other kinds of nastiness on it. Migrate the services to a clean box on an OS that still has updates for the upcoming time, for instance CentOS 6 or Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server.

Comment: Thanks Mike - we're in the process of planning a switch to 12.04 currently. Its a bit of a sorry situation that the server hasn't been receiving updates... as you say far from ideal.